# avro data validation with the schema

Tags: validation, hadoop, hive, avro

I'm new to this data validation and related concept, please excuse me if it is a simple question, help me with the steps to achieve this.

Use case:  Validating AVRO file (Structure and Data)

**Inputs:**

1. We are going to receive a AVRO file’s
2. We will have a schema file in a note pad (ex- field name, data type and size etc)

**Validation:**

1. Need to validate AVRO file with structure (schema-i.e field, data type, size etc)
2. Need to validate number and decimal format while viewing from Hive

So far I'm able to achieve is to get the schema from the avro file using the avro jar.

Comment: It isnt clear what your question actually is or what you're having problems with.

Comment: Actually i will be getting avro files from external source and I will have separate schema file. I need to validate weather the data is present as per the schema i.e if the 1st column is (id, int) in data file, its should be same in the schema file. To be simple data validation need to be done before loading the data into table.

Comment: @Dinesh: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: no @Shankar i'm not able to find the answer.